How to create a dynamic matrix-style input table in AppSheet with row and column combinations?
I’m building an app in AppSheet where I need to create a matrix-style input table that allows users to input data dynamically. Specifically, I want the rows to represent one category (e.g., memory options) and the columns to represent another category (e.g., color options). Users should be able to fill in values in the table cells, and these values should be stored properly in the backend.
Use Case
Parent Table:
Contains a unique identifier (ParentID) and other metadata.
Example:



ParentID
Name
Region
Type




PARENT01
Example A
Europe
Type1



Child Table (Matrix Data):
Contains:
ParentID (Ref column linking to the parent table).
RowValue (e.g., memory options: 64GB, 128GB).
ColumnValue (e.g., color options: Red, Blue, Black).
Value (the user-entered value for the cell).
Example:



ID
ParentID
RowValue
ColumnValue
Value




C001
PARENT01
64GB
Red
100


C002
PARENT01
64GB
Blue
150


C003
PARENT01
128GB
Red
200



Expected Behavior:
In the parent form, the inline table should display a grid:

Rows represent memory options (RowValue).

Columns represent color options (ColumnValue).

Users can input data into each cell of the grid (e.g., Value).


The entered data should be saved to the Child Table (Matrix Data).
The Problem
I’m not sure how to configure AppSheet to display a matrix-style table in the parent form where rows and columns dynamically adapt based on parent metadata (e.g., the available memory and color options).
I want to allow users to input values directly into the table cells, but AppSheet's default inline table layout doesn’t seem to support this structure.
What I’ve Tried
Parent-Child Relationship:
Set up a virtual column (e.g., Related MatrixData) in the parent table with the formula:
REF_ROWS("MatrixData", "ParentID")
Configured the child table (MatrixData) with:
A ParentID column as a Ref to the parent table.
A column for rows (RowValue).
A column for columns (ColumnValue).
Manual Data Entry:
Pre-populated some data in the MatrixData table, but I can only see a flat list of rows in the inline table instead of a matrix-style layout.
Dynamic Prepopulation:
Attempted to use a Bot to generate all combinations of rows (RowValue) and columns (ColumnValue) based on the parent record, but couldn’t achieve a grid-style layout in the app.
What I Need
Matrix-Style Input Table:
Guidance on how to configure a table where:
Rows represent RowValue (e.g., memory options).
Columns represent ColumnValue (e.g., color options).
Users can input data for each combination (e.g., Value).
Dynamic Prepopulation:
A way to prepopulate the child table with all combinations of RowValue and ColumnValue dynamically when a new parent record is created.
Example Configuration:
If this requires a custom approach (e.g., AppScript or AppSheet Bots), a detailed step-by-step example would be greatly appreciated.
Example Data
Parent Table:



ParentID
Name
Region
Type




PARENT01
Example A
Europe
Type1



Child Table (Matrix Data):



ID
ParentID
RowValue
ColumnValue
Value




C001
PARENT01
64GB
Red
100


C002
PARENT01
64GB
Blue
150


C003
PARENT01
128GB
Red
200



Example Layout in App
I want the inline table in the parent form to look something like this:



Memory / Color
Red
Blue
Black




64GB
100
150
120


128GB
200
250
180



Where users can directly enter values into the cells (e.g., 100, 150, etc.).

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.
